# How to remove failed workflows from a workflow set?

Tags: r, tidymodels

Following https://www.tmwr.org/grid-search.html#efficient-grids, I tried to run a workflow set with 12 models. However, for some reason, 5 had no results.

```
> race_results
# A workflow set/tibble: 12 × 4
   wflow_id             info             option    result    
   <chr>                <list>           <list>    <list>    
 1 MARS                 <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <race[+]> 
 2 CART                 <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <race[+]> 
 3 CART_bagged          <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <rsmp[+]> 
 4 RF                   <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <race[+]> 
 5 boosting             <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <race[+]> 
 6 Cubist               <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <race[+]> 
 7 SVM_radial           <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <race[+]> 
 8 SVM_poly             <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <list [0]>
 9 KNN                  <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <list [0]>
10 neural_network       <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[4]> <list [0]>
11 full_quad_linear_reg <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <list [0]>
12 full_quad_KNN        <tibble [1 × 4]> <opts[3]> <list [0]>

> race_results %>% autoplot()
Error in `halt()`:
! There were 5 workflows that had no results.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

How do I remove the last 5 workflows so I get autoplot() the workflows that worked? I used the same data in the link.

Comment: Was this using the same dataset as in the book? If not, can you create a small reproducible example (a [reprex](https://www.tidyverse.org/help/)) showing how this problem occurred for you?

Comment: Yes, I used the same dataset. I tried to reproduce this error with the same data but I could not. However, I think my question stands because this has happened before in other situations and I wish to evaluate partial results.

Comment: I would think `race_results %>% filter(lengths(result) > 1)` should work.

Comment: Oops, was too hasty: use `race_results %>% filter(lengths(result) > 0)` with `> 0` not `> 1`.